# What is the most efficient way to convert a Matrix into Vector of SVectors in Julia?

Tags: julia

I'm looking for the most efficient and fastest way to create a vector of SVectors from a 2D Matrix in Julia, dynamically. Suppose I have the following Matrix:

```
julia> r = rand(1000, 5);
```

Then I want to convert it to the exact type `Vector{SVector{5, Float64}}`. I tried the following, but I'm looking for a faster way:

```
julia> using StaticArrays

julia> function create_VSVec(data::Matrix{T}) where T
         ldim, mdim = argmin(size(data)), argmax(size(data))
         len_sv = size(data, ldim)
         sv = Vector{SVector{len_sv, T}}(undef, size(data, mdim))
         for idx in axes(sv, 1)
           sv[idx] = SVector{len_sv, T}(selectdim(data, mdim, idx))
         end
         return sv
       end;

julia> @benchmark create_VSVec($r)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 2993 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  1.415 ms … 22.241 ms  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 91.78%
 Time  (median):     1.518 ms              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   1.665 ms ±  1.275 ms  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  4.76% ±  5.78%

      █▃           
  ▂▃▆▇██▇▆▅▄▃▄▃▃▃▃▄▃▃▃▃▄▄▃▃▃▃▃▃▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▂▁▂▂▂▂ ▃
  1.41 ms        Histogram: frequency by time        2.31 ms <

 Memory estimate: 703.19 KiB, allocs estimate: 14480.

julia> a = create_VSVec(r);

julia> a[1] == r[1, :]
true
```

Answer (score 3):

A list-comprehension is 2X faster than `create_VSVec2`.

```
julia> r = rand(1000, 5);

julia> @benchmark create_VSVec2($r)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1 evaluation.
 Range (min … max):  12.500 μs …  4.741 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 98.95%
 Time  (median):     21.750 μs              ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   21.849 μs ± 96.395 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  11.44% ±  2.93%

  ▆█▄                 ▁▃▄▅▆▄▅▄▂▁ ▁             ▂              ▂
  ███▇▅▃▄▂▂▄▃▄▅▄▄▄▃▃▅▄█████████████▇▇▆▆▅▅▃▅▇▇▇███▆▅▆▅▆▆▆▇▆▆▆▇ █
  12.5 μs      Histogram: log(frequency) by time      39.9 μs <

 Memory estimate: 39.78 KiB, allocs estimate: 15.

julia> @benchmark [SVector{5,Float64}(i) for i in eachrow($r)]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 8 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   2.400 μs … 716.087 μs  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 97.09%
 Time  (median):      6.094 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   12.261 μs ±  34.098 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  19.12% ±  7.80%

      ▆█▅▅▂                    ▄▅▆▅▄▄▄▃▃▃▂▂▂▁▂▁                ▂
  ▆▄▅██████▇▆▆▄▄▆▄▄▅▄▃▄▃▆▄▄▄▅▅▆██████████████████▇▇▇▆▇▆▆▆▅▄▅▄▄ █
  2.4 μs        Histogram: log(frequency) by time      24.8 μs <

 Memory estimate: 39.11 KiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

Comment: Or, `SVector{5,Float64}.(eachrow(r))` for a shorter form.

Comment: In this case, the `reinterpret` does it much faster. Check my answer.

Comment: It doesn't do what you might think it does.

Answer (score 0):

Following the approach in the OP, and considering the important note that [@DNF mentioned in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74924565/what-is-the-most-efficient-way-to-convert-a-matrix-into-vector-of-svectors-in-ju#comment132221243_74924566), using `reinterpret` in the following way would make it ~90X faster and 18X lower in memory allocation:

```
julia> function create_VSVec2(data::Matrix{T}) where T
         ldim = argmin(size(data))
         ldim == 1 ? d = data : d = data'
         sv = identity.(reinterpret(SVector{5, Float64}, vec(d)))
         return sv
       end;

julia> @benchmark create_VSVec2($r)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 6 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   4.167 μs …  1.611 ms  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 98.04%
 Time  (median):     22.283 μs              ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   21.380 μs ± 55.021 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  16.17% ±  6.87%

  ▁█▆▄▁▁               ▃▄▄▄▄▆▆▆▅▃▂▁▁▂▂▂▁▁▁                    ▂
  ██████▇▇▆▄▅▅▃▅▅▃▅▄▇███████████████████████▇▇▇▇▇▇▇▆▅▆▆▆▆▆▅▅▆ █
  4.17 μs      Histogram: log(frequency) by time        50 μs <

 Memory estimate: 39.19 KiB, allocs estimate: 4.

julia> a = create_VSVec2(r);

julia> a[1] == r[1, :]
true

julia> typeof(a)
Vector{SVector{5, Float64}} (alias for Array{SArray{Tuple{5}, Float64, 1, 5}, 1})
```

But, if I use the `reinterpret` without any other calculations, I get the best performance:

```
julia> r = rand(5, 1000);

julia> @benchmark reinterpret(SVector{5, Float64}, $r)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1000 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  9.600 ns … 51.800 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     9.800 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   9.898 ns ±  0.767 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

      █   ▆        ▄    ▇   ▂                                ▂
  ▆▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▁▆▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▃▁▁▁▇▁▁▁▇ █
  9.6 ns       Histogram: log(frequency) by time     10.9 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark [SVector{5,Float64}(i) for i in eachcol($r)]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 7 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   3.500 μs … 915.714 μs  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 96.56%
 Time  (median):     24.486 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   22.559 μs ±  47.537 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  15.27% ±  7.51%

   ▄█▄▁▁▁                   ▂▂▂▄▃▃▅▆▅█▆▃▁▁▁▁▁▁               ▁ ▂
  ▇███████▅▆▆▇▄▄▃▆▅▁▃▆▆▃▅▇▆▆██████████████████████▇█▇▇▆█▆█▇███ █
  3.5 μs        Histogram: log(frequency) by time      41.4 μs <

 Memory estimate: 39.11 KiB, allocs estimate: 2.

julia> r = rand(1000, 5);

julia> @benchmark reinterpret(SVector{5, Float64}, $r)
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 1000 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):  9.300 ns … 58.300 ns  ┊ GC (min … max): 0.00% … 0.00%
 Time  (median):     9.400 ns              ┊ GC (median):    0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   9.545 ns ±  1.078 ns  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  0.00% ± 0.00%

  █  █   ▁       ▇   ▅                                       ▂
  █▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁█▁▁▁▆▁▁▃▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▁▇▁▁▁█▁▁▁▅▁▁▁▄▁▁▆ █
  9.3 ns       Histogram: log(frequency) by time     10.8 ns <

 Memory estimate: 0 bytes, allocs estimate: 0.

julia> @benchmark [SVector{5,Float64}(i) for i in eachrow($r)]
BenchmarkTools.Trial: 10000 samples with 7 evaluations.
 Range (min … max):   3.814 μs … 867.043 μs  ┊ GC (min … max):  0.00% … 96.02%
 Time  (median):     24.071 μs               ┊ GC (median):     0.00%
 Time  (mean ± σ):   21.553 μs ±  47.004 μs  ┊ GC (mean ± σ):  15.52% ±  7.48%

  ▂▇█▅▃▃▂                   ▁▁▃▃▃▆▇▅▇▇▄▃▂▂▁▁▁▁                 ▃
  ██████████▇▆▅▃▇▅▁▅▆▇▅▅▆▆▄▇████████████████████████▇▇▆▇▇█▇██▇ █
  3.81 μs       Histogram: log(frequency) by time      41.7 μs <

 Memory estimate: 39.11 KiB, allocs estimate: 2.
```

Comment: This is not what SVectors are for. You use them for when the sizes are known statically. If you determine their lengths dynamically (eg. from inout array sizes) they lose their advantage.

Comment: @DNF, wow! What's the problem with getting the length from the input? wouldn't it be static for each input?

Comment: The purpose of StaticArrays is to optimize the compiled code for a given array size, which must be known at compile time. The array size is part of the type, and when this isn't known at compile time, you have a type instability (type depends on runtime value.)

Comment: @Shayan, it took me a moment to realize the typo, because it sounds like things I would say, but the quote in the question is from DNF, not me.

Comment: @DanGetz, Oh god :D I was so tired at that moment. I should edit many things @_@